# Order 7 peoples in a row

Tags: combinatorics

There are 7 people to arrange in a row.

peoples A and B should sit when between there are 2 other people (a gap of 2).

How many ways are there to arrange the 7 people.

**Answer 1**: there are 2! to choose one of A or B, then the other will be placed and there are 4 placed for A and B, so we are left with 5 people so it is $4*2!5!$


**Answer 2**: there are 2! to arrange A and B like above, then we will choose 2 from the 5 people that are left $5\choose2$ those 2 can be arrange in 2 ways so it is ${5\choose2}2!$ no for the problem, we are left to arrange 3 so that answer will be
$2!{5\choose2}2!3!$ but the written answer is $2!{5\choose2}2!4!$  why is it?

Comment: I could edit the post for you if you wish, but it's a *row* you have in mind. Please correct.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $4$ ways to select the positions in which $A$ and $B$ shall be:  $(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,7)$ and $2$ ways to select who will sit in each of those $2$ positions. There are $5!$ ways to arrange the remaining persons.

Final answer: $4\cdot2\cdot5!$

Comment: you mean 4?
I got it is is 3!*4 (because of those 4 place to put A and B)

Comment: but there are $5$ positions: $(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,7)$

Comment: @Bananarama There is to be a gap of two persons: $(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)$. Your placements allow only one person between A, B.

Comment: oh, youŕe right then.